# Is it possible to make a stacked b-table with multiple items with bootstrap-vue?

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-vue, stacked

I would like to display multiple items in a bootstrap-vue b-table. Is it possible to do so with a stacked table? The documentation only shows examples of stacked tables with a single item.

How would I specify the fields or items? This does not work. This code creates a stacked table with two columns (column headers on the left and values on the right). Instead of displaying the two items side by side on the left half of the table, the column headers repeat and everything is organized in the same 2 vertical columns.

```
<template>
    ...
    <b-table
      small
      stacked
      :fields="fooParameters"
      :items="foos"
      :busy="true"
      show-empty
      empty-text="No duplicates"
    >
    </b-table>
   ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  duplicates: [{fooName: "Alice", fooAge: "25"}, {fooName: "Bob": fooAge: "24"}]
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#stacked-tables) shows an example with 3 items in a stacked table. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. I must have missed this. I’ll check again.

Comment: No. I am looking for each item to have its own column

Answer (score 0):

The `stacked` prop will generate a row for each item, but since that's not what you're looking for, you will have to create the functionality of having items be horizontal each having they own column.

I believe the below snippet is what you're looking for, and if not you can maybe use it as  a starting reference.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    fields() {
      //'isRowHeader: true' to render it as a TH instead of TD
      // Formatter to capitalize the first letter, can be removed
      let fields = [{
        key: "type",
        stickyColumn: true,
        isRowHeader: true,
        formatter: this.ucFirstLetter
      }];

      Object.keys(this.results).forEach((key) => {
        // Since the key is just an index, we hide it by setting label to an empty string.
        fields.push({
          key: key,
          label: ""
        });
      });

      return fields;
    },
    items() {
      const items = [];

      /* map our columuns */
      const cols = Object.keys(this.results);

      /* 
        map our types based on the first element 
        requires all the elements to contain the same properties,
        or at least have the first one contain all of them
      */
      const types = Object.keys(this.results[cols[0]]);

      /* create an item for each type */
      types.forEach((type) => {
        const item = {
          type: type
        };

        /* fill up item based on our columns */
        cols.forEach((col) => {
          item[col] = this.results[col][type];
        });

        items.push(item);
      });

      return items;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      results: [{
          correct: 0.007,
          errors: 0.081,
          missing: 0.912
        },
        {
          correct: 0.008,
          errors: 0.098,
          missing: 0.894
        },
        {
          correct: 0.004,
          errors: 0.089,
          missing: 0.91
        },
        {
          correct: 0.074,
          errors: 0.07,
          missing: 0.911
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ucFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" small bordered striped sticky-header no-border-collapse responsive>
  </b-table>
</div>
```